# How to replace fragment outside of bottom sheet by clicking button inside of bottom sheet?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-fragments, android-architecture-navigation, bottom-sheet

So I've decided to make my app with single Activity. In one of my fragments (`fragment(A)`) I open `bottom sheet` by clicking `Button open BS`. Now the tricky park, inside bottom sheet there is a `FragmentContainerView` that has two fragments inside and I want to click `Button B` inside this `FragmentContainerView` (in `fragment(B)`) that would change `fragment(A)` to `fragment(C)` and close bottom sheet.

I'm aware that by using code below it's possible to swap fragment and close bottom sheet (here I'm clicking button outside of `FragmentContainerView` but still inside bottom sheet):

```
ButtonSH.setOnClickListner{
    parentFragmentManager.commit {
          // replace fragment
          replace<FragmentC>(R.id.fragment_container_that_holds_fragmets_A_and_C)
    }
    // close bottom sheet
    dismiss()
}
```

But I just can't understand how to do the same by clicking `Button B` inside `FragmentContainerView` in `fragment(b)`.

If it matters, `fragment(A)` is not directly inside activity, it is inside a few other fragments.

Here is an image for better understanding:

[image: visualisation for better understanding]

Comment: Use an interface to comunicate between fragment B and Bottom sheet.

Comment: @Mike087 as far as I understood from googling interfaces are used to communicate through activity(it's not possible to use it in my case). I also tried FragmentResultApi but it seems not to work with nested fragments. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So my solution was to make sharedViewModel for bottom sheet and its fragments, and to use another sharedViewModel for container that holds fragment(A) and for bottom sheet. I observe variables inside viewModels to replace fragments. For official documentation visit [this](https://developer.android.com/guide/fragments/communicate)